# Find Matrix T with respect to the basis beta

Tags: linear-algebra, linear-transformations, change-of-basis

Let T : R^3 -> R^3 be the linear transformation

(a) The matrix of T with respect to the standard basis alpha of R^3

(b) The matrix of T with respect to the basis beta

$$
   T\begin{pmatrix}
    x  \\
    y  \\
    z  \\
    \end{pmatrix}= \begin{pmatrix}
    5x & + & z \\
    3x & +2y & -3z \\
    5x \\
    \end{pmatrix}
$$
For the standard basis alpha and the basis beta given by 
$$
    \begin{matrix}
    1 & 1 & 1 \\
    1 & -1 & 1 \\
    2 & 1 & 1 \\
    \end{matrix}
$$
(a)
$$
    \begin{pmatrix}
   T
    \end{pmatrix} = \begin{pmatrix}
    5 & 0 & 1 \\
    3 & 2 & -3 \\
    5 & 0 & 0 \\
    \end{pmatrix}
$$
(b)

$$
   T\begin{pmatrix}
    1  \\
    1  \\
    2  \\
    \end{pmatrix}= \begin{pmatrix}
    7 \\
    -1 \\
    5 \\
    \end{pmatrix}
$$

This is in my textbook i can't seem to figure out where the 7,-1,5 vector comes from. This is in terms of beta. Any help is really appreciated it.

Comment: Just apply the first formula for vector (1,1,2) and you get (7,-1,5)

Comment: Wow ok, thank you.. I think im retarded.